# Visual studio .NET MAUI windows build button is missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

Basically, i have this small MAUI project and somewhere along the way, the Windows deployment button is gone. I can no longer deploy and test on windows. I have no idea what i did wrong.
Please, see my .csproj file and screenshot below. Maybe im missing something.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MAUIDependencySample</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MAUIDependencySample</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.example</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>0D7F5EAA-B445-45A1-9898-B9535F8F0DED</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">27.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <CodesignKey>Apple Development: example (PCQ252A654)</CodesignKey>
        <!--<CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>-->
        <CodesignProvision>Example Development</CodesignProvision>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net6.0-ios'">
      <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="1.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net" Version="4.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel.OidcClient" Version="5.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="LibBLEStandard" Version="1.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="MauiLibBLE" Version="1.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Refractored.MvvmHelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.ObjectModel" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\BarcodeScanView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\BluetoothFunctionsView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\HomeView.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

So as you can see from the screenshot, there is no button to deploy to windows.

Info: im on the latest visual studio at the moment, 17.4.2. If i do a brand new MAUI project, i can see the windows button.

I have tried changing the target and minimum windows sdk version.

I have also tried going back and forth with .net 6 and 7, but still no luck.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Force VS to treat this as a brand new project: Close Visual Studio. Delete hidden `.vs` folder in your solution folder, as well as `bin` and `obj`. Alternatively, make sure it is saved in a source repository, delete your solution folder, download sources again.

Comment: In the picture you provide, there is a Framework option. So can you change the `Framework` to the `net7.0-windows`?